# javascript change pasted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have text in contenteditable div and user can copy some its parts and paste inside this div. But there are styles coping with text, so i need to take copied part and take just text from it, so i'm making

```
 <div id="text-container" contenteditable ng-paste="textPaste($event)"></div>
```

and js:

```
$scope.textPaste= function (e) {
    var pasted_text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    e.originalEvent.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', pasted_text);
};
```

So I really get the text I need to the variable pasted_text , but it's not pasted instead of origin text. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean in that case?

Comment: can we use jQuery for this.?

Comment: @Marimba, text still pastes with styles

Comment: @Jithin Raj P R, yes

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: create detached DOM element, paste formatted text into it and then return its `textContent` property:

```
var phantomEl = document.createElement('div');
phantomEl.innerHTML = pasted_text;
var cleanText = phantomEl.textContent;
```

After this, you will have plain text in the `cleanText` variable.

Comment: Sorry I didn't say it before. I do not have problems with getting just text (without tags and styles), I have problem with pasting it instead